# SimpleMessageListenerContainer method should stop processing after timeout

Tags: java, spring, jms

I have JVM1 sending requests to JVM2 synchronously via MQ. This is achieved using JmsInvokerServiceExporter ,SimpleMessageListenerContainer and JmsInvokerProxyFactoryBean. The listener method in JVM2 is written such that should any exception arise during processing, it will fabricate a default response indicating that something went wrong. If everything goes fine, it will send successful response.

Now what I am looking for is if the listener method is taking more time than a predefined period, an exception be thrown so that the listener can stop further procesing and send the default response back to JVM1. Basically JVM2 listener should not process beyond time X sec and should be able to send default response back.

I can make the JVM1 time out after X secs but then I won't get the default response that I am expecting from JVM2. Can someone please let me know if such a thing can be achieved or not? The code snippet for setting up the communication between jvm1 and 2 is given below.

Expose a pojo Calculator.java service for remoting over JMS using JMSInvokerServiceExporter

```
<bean id="calculatorService"    class="com.spring.remoting.service.impl.SalaryCalculator" />

<bean id="remoteCalculatorService" class="org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerServiceExporter">
    <property name="service" ref="calculatorService">
    <property name="serviceInterface"   value="com.spring.remoting.service.Calculator" />
</bean>
```

Listener and Invoker

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
   <property name="destination" ref="myQueue"/>
   <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="3"/>
   <property name="messageListener" ref="remoteCalculatorService"/>
</bean>  

<bean id="remoteCalculatorService" class="org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
     <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.spring.remoting.service.Calculator" />
     <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
     <property name="queue" ref="myQueue"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Did you try setting the timeout on the JmsInvokerProxyFactoryBean and was that result not what you wanted?

Comment: I can timeout the client but then I want the response from the listener. That's why I was asking if there is a way to do that in the listener rather than timing out the client.